# How to Magento remove default store view code from url?

Tags: magento-1.9, url, url-rewrite, store-view, seo

We need your help to solve this problem.

we have a 2 view store in English and Arabic

URLs now

www.example.com/en
www.example.com/ar

we need to remove code view in English version only as default store view.

without **sub domain** solution.

we tried [Jreinke Magento hide default store code](https://github.com/jreinke/magento-hide-default-store-code) but its not working well.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by code view?

Comment: Hi @AdarshKhatri, i mean store view code like en and ar above

Comment: are you trying to redirect to `ar` site when customer visit to `en` site?Or are you trying to disable english site?

Comment: @AdarshKhatri no keep both of them but we need to remove the en code from url.

Answer (score -1):

When Magento sites add a second store on the same domain there is a problem with legacy requests to old URLs. This is bad SEO and a bad experience for customers too
I just Resolved this problem by this extension

https://github.com/lalitmohann/Magento-Store-Codes

Extension available on github. [click here](https://github.com/lalitmohann/Magento-Store-Codes)

i solved this Problem , i hope that's save others Person here is the details :

1- Download the zip existe in this page : https://github.com/lalitmohann/Magento-Store-Codes

2- unzip the file and put the folder in {app/code/community/}

3- In your backoffice go to "System > Tools > Compilation" and click the rebuild button

4- always in backoffice got to "System > Configuration > Web > URL options" and set the attribute "and default store view" to No and save the configuration

5- Clear your cach magento and enjoy your application :) .